# jooq fetch custom object has ZonedDateTime field met DataTypeException

Tags: timestamp, jooq

`java-1.8 jooq-3.10.0 SpringBoot-1.5.7`

`myCondition = create
    .select(...
        TABLE_AL.START_DATE.as("table_al_start_date"), 
        TABLE_BR.START_DATE.as("table_br_start_date")))
    .from(MAIN).innerJoin(TABLE_AL).onkey()
    .innerJoin(TABLE_BR).onkey()
    .where(DSL.trueCondition());
List<MyObject> myObjList = myCondition.fetch().into(MyObject.class)`

`class MyObject(){
    ZonedDateTime tableAlStartDate;
    ZonedDateTime tableBrStartDate;
    ...
}`

my Object has fields from several table , 
`table_al_start_date` is `java.time.ZonedDateTime` , 
`timestamp without time zone,nullable` in `PostgreSQL`,

a DataType Exception will thrown when fetch into `MyObject`
`Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: 
    Cannot convert from 1511971200000 (class java.lang.Long) to class java.time.ZonedDateTime
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:1169)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.toDate(Convert.java:1121)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:823)`

if use 
`.select(TABLE_A.START_DATE.as("table_a_start_date").cast(ZonedDateTime.class)`
will met
`org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.time.ZonedDateTime is not supported in dialect null`

also tried add a setter `setTableAlStartDate(Long long)`, won't work.

I found Converter at [custom-bindings](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual-single-page/#custom-bindings) , what should do after create a custom converter, where should 
`DataType<LocalDate> type = SQLDataType.DATE.asConvertedDataType(new LocalDateConverter());` this be?

what should do with this `ZonedDateTime` field?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this a good practice, works for me:

```
myCondition = create
    .select(,,,
        DSL.field("table_al.start_date", SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP
            .asConvertedDataType(ts2zonedConverter))
            .as("table_al_start_date"),,,, 
    .from(,,,);
```

myConverter

```
public class TsZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, ZonedDateTime> {
@Override public ZonedDateTime from(Timestamp t) {
        return t == null ? null : t.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    }
@Override public Timestamp to(ZonedDateTime u) {
        return u == null ? null : Timestamp.from(u.toInstant());
    }
}
```